# Mysql limit, but with adding some more rows

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
name   | age
John   | 35
Amanda | 34
Jane   | 34
Jack   | 34
Craig  | 32
Jason  | 32
Phil   | 32
Kris   | 32
Tyler  | 25
Harry  | 25
Duke   | 24
```

I want to order it by age desc and select first five rows. But if there are more people with the same age as in row 5, I want them in my result too. Something like: (`SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 0, 5 as W) UNION (SELECT * FROM people WHERE age = W[4].age`)

So the result of example above would be:

```
John   | 35
Amanda | 34
Jane   | 34
Jack   | 34
Craig  | 32
Jason  | 32
Phil   | 32
Kris   | 32
```

- John, Amanda, Jane, Jack, Craig are in the result, because there are first five oldest
- Jason, Phil, Kris are in the result because they are the same age as last row five

Is there any way how to do it? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,age INT NOT NULL)
;

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('John'   ,35),
('Amanda' ,34),
('Jane'   ,34),
('Jack'   ,34),
('Craig'  ,32),
('Jason'  ,32),
('Phil'   ,32),
('Kris'   ,32),
('Tyler'  ,25),
('Harry'  ,25),
('Duke'   ,24);

SELECT DISTINCT y.*
           FROM
              ( SELECT *
                  FROM my_table
                 ORDER
                    BY age DESC
                 LIMIT 5
              ) x
           JOIN my_table y
             ON y.age = x.age;
+--------+-----+
| name   | age |
+--------+-----+
| John   |  35 |
| Amanda |  34 |
| Jane   |  34 |
| Jack   |  34 |
| Craig  |  32 |
| Jason  |  32 |
| Phil   |  32 |
| Kris   |  32 |
+--------+-----+
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/CPRY41026)**

Comment: what you use to format the table? the one I use it is offline now

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I just use my command line interface and TextPad.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You have to use a inner query to select the top 5 ages, then invert the order to select the last one.</strike>

Use `Limit 4, 1` to skip first 4 and select the last one

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/HKD40834)**

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM people 
      ORDER BY age DESC 
      LIMIT 5 ) as w
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM people 
WHERE age = (SELECT age
             FROM Table1
             ORDER BY `age` DESC
             LIMIT 4, 1)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: @Strawberry I bet there is, still looking for a workaround, not found it yet. :( feel free to post another answer

Comment: @Strawberry Not sure how `LIMIT` work with two parameters maybe `LIMIT 4, 5` ?

Comment: @Strawberry No you were right, Make me check documentation `LIMIT 4, 1` skip 4 and select the last one

Comment: The output's the only thing I dislike about rextester - oh and that annoying ad on the right hand side.

Comment: @Strawberry For  output I use `snag it` so is just copy paste, ad doesnt botter me much, I have limit vision on the right eye.

Answer (score 0):

What if you just try like

```
SELECT * FROM people
WHERE Age IN (SELECT DISTINCT Age FROM people ORDER BY Age DESC LIMIT 5)
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, Yes make sense